# Coverings of (DM) stacks and categories of descent data

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stacks

If $X$ is a DM stack, we know that there is a surjective étale morphism $U \to X$ with $U$ a scheme. Combining Lemma 4.5 of [these notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/qcohrevised.pdf) and Proposition 12.7.4 of [Champs Algébriques](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-24899-6) one should be able to define an sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules (in the étale topology) by an étale sheaf of $\mathcal O_U$-modules $\mathcal F$ together with suitable gluing data dictated by the "category of descent data" $\operatorname{Des}(U/X)$, see the discussion before Lemma 4.5 on the [aforementioned notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/qcohrevised.pdf).

I hope that the above summary is correct, and I was thinking: what about taking different covers? For example, if we cover $U$ with affines $U_i \hookrightarrow U$, we should get something which looks like an "étale covering of the stack $X$", namely $\mathfrak U = \{U_i \to X \}$. Is it reasonable to expect that we have a category of descent data $\operatorname{Des}(\mathfrak U / X)$ which enables us to define sheaves of modules as follows? A sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules would be a family $\mathcal F_i$ of sheaves of $\mathcal O_{U_i}$-modules together with suitable gluing data. Does this make sense? Is there perhaps a reference where I can find explanations around this issue?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_on_an_algebraic_stack

Comment: I don't see how that Wikipedia entry answers...

Comment: Hi Francesco, yes, if you call $U'=\bigsqcup U_i$, then the composite $U'\to U\to X$ will be another atlas for $X$, and the machinery in your first paragraph applies to this as well.